# Can I auto switch phone to silent triggered by specific wifi connection?

Tags: automation, silent-mode, xiaomi-pocophone-f1

Specifically my phone is Xiaomi Pocophone F1 and I'd like it to automatically switch into silent/DND mode as soon as it connects to the office Wifi.

The phone is not rooted and runs Muii version 12.03

Can this be achieved?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A [Tasker app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en&gl=US) could be a solution.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).